# Hide softkeyboard in Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

How do I hide the softkeyboard for showing up when focusing an `Entry` in Xamarin.forms portable forms project? I assume we have to write platform specific renderers for that, but the following does not work:

I create my own entry subclass:

```
public class MyExtendedEntry : Entry
{
}
```

and then in the xamarin.android project my renderer:

```
public class MyExtendedEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (Control != null)
        {
            new Handler().Post(delegate
            {
                var imm = (InputMethodManager)Control.Context.GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);
                var result = imm.HideSoftInputFromWindow(Control.WindowToken, 0);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The `OnElementChanged` is called as expected and when using `Handler.Post()` I also get a WindowToken instead of null. Sadly the return value from `HideSoftInputFromWindow` is always false and the softkeyboard still turns up when clicking on the Entry.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`OnElementChanged` is called whenever the view is initialized and attached to the view. What you want to do is to hide the keyboard when the entry is clicked, so you should add an event handler to `FocusChange` to the `Control`.

**Example:**

```
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (Control != null)
        {
            Control.Click += (sender, evt) => {
                new Handler().Post(delegate
                    {
                        var imm = (InputMethodManager)Control.Context.GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.InputMethodService);
                        var result = imm.HideSoftInputFromWindow(Control.WindowToken, 0);

                        Console.WriteLine(result);
                    });
            };

            Control.FocusChange += (sender, evt) => {
                new Handler().Post(delegate
                    {
                        var imm = (InputMethodManager)Control.Context.GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.InputMethodService);
                        var result = imm.HideSoftInputFromWindow(Control.WindowToken, 0);

                        Console.WriteLine(result);
                    });
            };
        }
    }
```

**Update:** Combined answer from @Vikram

**Update:** Added `Click` event handler

Comment: Sadly `result` is still false and the keyboard is shown.

Comment: I found that if the user clicks on it the second time, the focus didn't change and therefore I added also `Click` event handler. I tried on my Note 3 and it works and `True` is returned.

Comment: it is bad to show then hide keyboard.  Any solution to prevent it from showing on Entry Focus?

Comment: The cursor didnt show (even when focused). Selecting added it back `Control.SetSelection(0);` .

Answer (score 3):

Note: I am not versed in Xamarin.

In my experience, using `imm.HideSoftInputFromWindow(Control.WindowToken, 0)` immediately after the control receives focus produces dodgy results, even when using `Post`. I have had success using `PostDelayed` instead. The delay I use is 500ms.

Give this a try:

```
public class MyExtendedEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (Control != null)
        {
            new Handler().PostDelayed(delegate
            {
                var imm = (InputMethodManager)Control.Context.GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);
                var result = imm.HideSoftInputFromWindow(Control.WindowToken, 0);
            }, 500L);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Vikram This will hide keyboard right after it is displayed which is not great.  Is there a way to prevent it from showing entirely on Entry focus?

Answer (score 0):

The key to prevent the virtual keyboard from appearing is to override the Focus() method of Entry and NOT call the base method. Otherwise it will always appear occasionally, regardless what you do. This has the additional benefit of simplifying the needed code since you automatically gain control over the appearance and disapperarnce of the virtual keyboard. I have not found any negative sideeffects of this approach so far.

I have created a sample control with full control over the virtual keyboard and a small app that shows the usage.

Since this question is asked in several forums I decided to rather write a detailed Readme attached to the project that explains all key points of the implementation instead of duplicating the explanation in several different forums. I hope that is okay. If not, please let me know.

The whole project is available here:
https://github.com/UweReisewitz/XamarinAndroidEntry