# Xamarin PCL: Hide soft keyboard on android (Dependecy Service) doesn't work

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, android-softkeyboard, soft-keyboard

I trigger the code onfocus of an entry, but the hiding code in Android doesn't hide the soft keyboard.

### Interface

```
public interface IKeyboardService
{
    void Hide();
    void Show();
}
```

### ViewModel

```
public void OnFocused()
{
   var serv = DependencyService.Get<IKeyboardService>();

   if (cp.FindByName<SwitchCell>("SCell").On)
   {
      serv.Show();
   }
   else
   {
      serv.Hide();
   }
}
```

### Android Code

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(KeyboardService))]
namespace KeyboardHide.Droid.DependencyServices
{
    public class KeyboardService : IKeyboardService
    {
        public void Hide()
        {
            var inputMethodManager = Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context.GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService) as InputMethodManager;
            if (inputMethodManager != null && Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context is Activity)
            {
                var activity = Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context as Activity;
                var focusedView = activity.CurrentFocus;
                var token = focusedView == null ? null : focusedView.WindowToken;
                inputMethodManager.HideSoftInputFromInputMethod(token, HideSoftInputFlags.None);
            }
        }

        public void Show()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I also tried this code

### code

```
var inputMethodManager = Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context.GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService) as InputMethodManager;
if (inputMethodManager != null && Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context is Activity)
{
    var activity = Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context as Activity;
    var focusedView = activity.CurrentFocus;
    var token = focusedView == null ? null : focusedView.WindowToken;
    inputMethodManager.ToggleSoftInputFromWindow(token, ShowSoftInputFlags.None, HideSoftInputFlags.None);
}
```

this worked for me by another project ??

*Edit:

Previous project (Works for another project of mine):

```
var inputMethodManager = Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context.GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService) as InputMethodManager;
if (inputMethodManager != null && Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context is Activity)
{
    var activity = Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context as Activity;
    var focusedView = activity.CurrentFocus;
    var token = focusedView == null ? null : focusedView.WindowToken;
    inputMethodManager.ToggleSoftInputFromWindow(token, ShowSoftInputFlags.None, HideSoftInputFlags.None);
}
```

But for my new project it doesn't work. I still see the keyboard, it doesn't hide it and I tried also:

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => serv.Hide());
```

Comment: inputMethodManager.HideSoftInputFromWindow(token, 0); also doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

The following Android code works for me (got this code from someone else but cannot remember where now, I assume the Xamarin Forums). It has the added benefit of being able to be `await`'ed, but if you do not want that, you can remove the `TaskCompletionSource` stuff:

```
public Task<bool> DismissKeyboardAsync() {
    TaskCompletionSource<bool> result = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    try {
        View view = ((MainActivity)Forms.Context).CurrentFocus;

        IBinder windowToken = view?.WindowToken;

        if(windowToken != null) {
            ((InputMethodManager)Forms.Context.GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService)).HideSoftInputFromWindow(windowToken, HideSoftInputFlags.None);
            result.TrySetResult(true);
            return result.Task;
        }

        result.TrySetResult(false);
    } catch(System.Exception exception) {
        System.Console.WriteLine("\nIn NativeHelper_Android.DismissKeyboardAsync() - Exception:\n{0}\n", exception);
        result.TrySetException(exception);
        result.TrySetResult(false);
    }

    return result.Task;
}
```

An example without `async` might be (this is untested code):

```
public void Hide() {
    try {
        View view = ((MainActivity)Forms.Context).CurrentFocus;

        IBinder windowToken = view?.WindowToken;

        if(windowToken != null) {
            ((InputMethodManager)Forms.Context.GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService)).HideSoftInputFromWindow(windowToken, HideSoftInputFlags.None);
        }
    } catch(System.Exception exception) {
        System.Console.WriteLine("\nIn NativeHelper_Android.DismissKeyboardAsync() - Exception:\n{0}\n", exception);
    }
}
```

Comment: doesn't work, on my previous project works it well, did i miss a configuration in android project maybe ?? Did you something special ?

Comment: @AliEren When you say it doesn't work, do you mean the keyboard does not go away? Also what is the difference between your previous project and the one that is not working? Finally, try running the code on the UI Thread like so: `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => serv.Hide());`

Comment: @AliEren I am not sure what the issue could be. It must be some difference between your previous project and your new one. I would suggest either going line by line and comparing the projects or you could simply set your `Entry.IsEnabled` to `false` which would also prevent the user from being able to type into the `Entry`. Would that work for you instead?

Comment: For later: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28835195/hide-softkeyboard-in-xamarin